# SQL Server Profiler Not Like Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-profiler

I am using SQL Server Profiler 2019. My "Not Like" filter on "Application" is not working. It is still getting values for "SQLAgent". See values below. How do I exclude those values properly?

[image]

Comment: Just a guess here...The Application name is not just SQLAgent.  So you may need a wildcard after SQLAgent in order to properly activate the "not like" filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard character for SQL Profiler is, like in SQL generally, `%`. So use `SQLAgent%` as your value for NOT LIKE and it should work.

As an aside, I love SQL Profiler too but you should ideally use Extended Events sessions which have a much lighter impact on the SQL Server and are way more powerful. You can easily start one by double-clicking on the XEvent Profiler > Standard node in SQL Server Management Studio's Object Explorer window:

[image: SMSS Object Explorer]

Then you can use the toolbar that appears to edit Filters etc. There's lots of good resources out there for getting to grips with extended events (XE) ... although I still prefer some things about SQL Profiler's UI.